# Python / Tkinter Is there a way to distinguish a programmatic change to a combo box from a user initiated change?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a GUI front-end for a network appliance where many of the parameters (Parameter1 and Parameter2 for this example) are best displayed as a combo box.  There is an implicit hierarchy of parameters where Parameter1 will change the value of Parameter2, but Parameter2 will not change Parameter1 and Parameter2 may be changed independently.

I can trap a user initiated change to Parameter1 and Parameter2, but when the user initiated change to Parameter1 causes a programmatic change to Parameter2 the trap on Parameter2 is also invoked.

Is there a clever way to work around this?

Sample code:

```
  import Tkinter as tk
  import ttk

  global parameter1
  global parameter2
  global list1
  global list2

  list1 = ["apple","bananna","orange"]
  list2 = ["moe","larry","curly"]

  def parameter1_changed(arg1,arg2,arg3):
      print "Selection for List 1 changed"
      print "arg1=%s  arg2=%s  arg3=%s"%(arg1,arg2,arg3)
      parameter2.set(list2[1])

  def parameter2_changed(arg1,arg2,arg3):
      print "Selection for List 2 changed"
      print "arg1=%s  arg2=%s  arg3=%s"%(arg1,arg2,arg3)

  root = tk.Tk()

  parameter1 = tk.StringVar()
  parameter1.set(list1[0])

  parameter2=tk.StringVar()
  parameter2.set(list2[0])

  tk.Label(root,text="List #1").grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=tk.E)
  ttk.Combobox(root,values=list1,textvariable=parameter1,state='readonly').grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=tk.W)
  tk.Label(root,text="List #2").grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=tk.E)
  ttk.Combobox(root,values=list2,textvariable=parameter2,state='readonly').grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=tk.W)

  parameter1.trace("w",parameter1_changed)
  parameter2.trace("w",parameter2_changed)

  root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a subclass of `StringVar` that allows you to disable callback triggers:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

global parameter1
global parameter2
global list1
global list2

class SuppressableStingVar(tk.StringVar):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        tk.StringVar.__init__(self, *args, **kargs)
        self.silenced = False
    def trace(self, mode, callback):
        conditional_callback = lambda *args, **kargs: callback(*args, **kargs) if not self.silenced else None
        tk.StringVar.trace(self, mode, conditional_callback)
    def set(self, value, suppress_callback = False):
        if suppress_callback:
            self.silenced = True
        tk.StringVar.set(self, value)
        self.silenced = False


list1 = ["apple","bananna","orange"]
list2 = ["moe","larry","curly"]

def parameter1_changed(arg1,arg2,arg3):
  print "Selection for List 1 changed"
  print "arg1=%s  arg2=%s  arg3=%s"%(arg1,arg2,arg3)
  parameter2.set(list2[1], True)

def parameter2_changed(arg1,arg2,arg3):
  print "Selection for List 2 changed"
  print "arg1=%s  arg2=%s  arg3=%s"%(arg1,arg2,arg3)

root = tk.Tk()

parameter1 = tk.StringVar()
parameter1.set(list1[0])

parameter2=SuppressableStingVar()
parameter2.set(list2[0])

tk.Label(root,text="List #1").grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=tk.E)
ttk.Combobox(root,values=list1,textvariable=parameter1,state='readonly').grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=tk.W)
tk.Label(root,text="List #2").grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=tk.E)
ttk.Combobox(root,values=list2,textvariable=parameter2,state='readonly').grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=tk.W)

parameter1.trace("w",parameter1_changed)
parameter2.trace("w",parameter2_changed)

root.mainloop()
```

Manipulating the first dropdown now produces the output:

```
Selection for List 1 changed
arg1=PY_VAR0  arg2=  arg3=w
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't  tell them apart. 
You have to either use some sort of signaling - a flag - or disconnect the function prior to do that change and reconnect afterwards.